# Reducing a system of non-linear ODEs to a single ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the system;

$$\frac{dX}{dt}=-\alpha XY$$
$$\frac{dY}{dt}=\alpha XY-\beta Y$$

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants

I need to reduce this system to a single ODE in  $X$ and $Y$ and solve analytically. The initial conditions being $X(0)=X_0,$ $Y(0)=Y_0$

My work:

I believe this system to be autonomous as neither ODE involves time explicitly on the RHS, so my thoughts are we can eliminate time and yield an expression relating $X$ and $Y$. That is,

$$\frac{dX}{dY}=\frac{\frac{dX}{dt}}{\frac{dY}{dt}}$$
$$\frac{dX}{dY}=\frac{-\alpha XY}{\alpha XY-\beta Y}=\frac{-\alpha X}{\alpha X-\beta}$$
We can then attempt to solve this through the separation of variables;
$$\int-1+\frac{\beta}{\alpha X}\ dX=\int dY$$
This could be the completely wrong direction but I always feel its good to add some of my own work, any prompts appreciated. I know these non-linear systems often don't have analytic solutions and require some form of linearization but given I have been asked to find it I assume one exists.

Comment: Double check the step where you go split up $\frac{-\alpha X}{\alpha X - \beta}$. You're otherwise on the right path.

Comment: Made the appropriate edit (I think) it still results in the same separable though doesn't it?

Comment: Yep. So you just need to solve this and incorporate the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the SIR model for epidemics.  A possible solution is to write

[image]

and the solution with the initial conditions ($Y(X_{0})=Y_{0}$) is

[image]

which is reduced to

[image]

Comment: Yes I was aware this was the SIR model in epidemiology, I found the general solution to the problem, is it possible to re-write the initial conditions in that fashion though?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.